# How to delete/clear Apache error logs in Plesk?

Tags: apache, logging, plesk

[image]

Why deleting APACHE ERROR log (mine is almost 50 MB in size) in Plesk check box / function disabled? Are Apache Error logs unsafe to delete/clear? Please take a look at the attached Plesk screenshot where 6 of the 9 check boxes are disabled to delete. Do you know why?

Comment: Hi, this is not a programming problem. Maybe your question fits better on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)